# Generate a random number and add 0 before it to ensure fixed number of digits

Tags: java, android, random

so I am trying to generate a random number. I am going to append the day and month as integers before the random number. This I am able to do by using the following code.

```
    Calendar calendar;
    calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    int day= calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1; //it treats Jan as 0 hence i add 1
    int num= Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(month)+String.valueOf(day));
```

Now i need to generate a random number but add 0s before it. For example today is 21st September so numbers will look like

```
    921 (num) + 22334 (random num) = 92122334
    921 (num) + 2 (random num) = 92100002
```

Basically add 0s to the start ensuring number of digits remain the same. The use case of this is an easier way of generating unique order numbers that have an inbuilt time stamp as well. I dont expect to process more than 200 orders a day hence taking a 5 digit random  number seems reasonable enough for probability of duplicates to be very small.

Comment: You can not prepend 0s to an integer, you need to store it in a String to do that

Comment: yes by default 0s to the left of a number are ignored. So how do I go about doing that? I cant think of an effective way

Comment: It's not possible, use a String

Comment: so I will need a for() loop to concatenate "0" to the number?

Comment: I would do `while(length < requiredLength) { x = "0" + x; }`

Comment: Side note: do not use ints. Do not use a String. Step back for a second and consider the properties of your ORDER number. Then do some object-oriented modelling and build the class(es) that you need. Overloading simple String objects or even primitive int types with the meaning that you describe is well ... a road to disaster (from an software engineering point of view)

Comment: No properties as such. Its just a number given to a customer for placing an order. The only requirement is uniqueness and readability. Hence im adding a timestamp in the start and a random number at the end. I will then convert this to hexadecimal or some other alphanumeric so it is limited to only 5-6 digits which is easy for humans to remember and understand.

Comment: All I am saying is: in a proper, object-oriented design, you can and should be using distinct types for distinct "things". What happens when the requirements to your order number change at some point; and a simple int won't do it any more? Happy reworking of your code then. The point is: if you just use plain numbers or strings to implement your business logic; then you **spread** the knowledge about the essentials of your order number all over the place. But it should be in **one central** place instead.

Comment: True, but i need this only for a prototype and I am generating only one 'type' of order. I understand that this is a horrible long term solution but for now it should do. At a later stage I will have to check what are 'best-practices' in Industries to generate consumer friendly order numbers.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Using a loop to append zeros to a string is something nobody should be doing. Java has built-in powerful ways to handle text formatting; use that; and don't try to re-invent what has be resolved many times before.

Comment: I've seen too many prototypes that were not thrown away. Instead, people had to live with the deficiencies of their "prototypes" for many months; even years. Meaning: even if you are working on a proof of concept - do you really think you will be so much quicker if you follow bad design and coding practices? What happens if requirements change during this initial phase? Long story short: I understand that writing "too much" throw away code isn't helpful; but neglecting base principles of good design isn't helpful either. You should be training the skills you need; not those that are "wrong"!

Comment: I understand your point and agree with you. I wont be that much quicker but I cant find adequate solutions to this, hence I had to come up with this scrappy 'solution' . It has been suggested to use UUIDs/ GUIDs and other such 16 digit alpha numeric which becomes too complex for users to handle. If i can find a better way, believe me i will go for it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions.

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
int num = 0;
num += (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 10_000_000;
num += calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) * 100_000;
num += your_random_number_lower_100000
```

second

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
String randomDigits = String.format("%d%02d%05d", 
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
        your_random_number_lower_100000
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use String format:**

```
String finalString = String.format("%d%05d", num, randomNum);
```

Here you can pass first parameter, Your calculation of day and month and second parameter Random number that got.

**%05d means:** If your integer number digit size will be less than 5 then it will append the 0 (zero) to make the number in 5 digit.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
int newnumber = 921*100000 + 2;
```

that gives 92100002. instead of 2 you can use any random number of course.
If you want to add zeros in front of the 921 so it becomes 0921 and for 1st September 0901 for example, you need to convert it to a string and check the length, and add zeros till you have the length that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a `String` by such way:

```
 String value = String.valueOf(randomNum); //your random num should have 5 digits or less
 int N = 5; //your length
 while (value.length < N)
   value = "0" + value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to store this as a string (which it seems you are already doing since you are adding 921 and 22334 and getting 92122334?) the easiest way would be to add 0's to the start of the string until it reaches a certain length.

`StringBuilder numberString = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
numberString.append(yourNumber);`

`while(numberString.length() < maxSize)
   numberString.insert('0');`